# AJAX call finishes after rest of the script

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I Have an AJAX call to get entry's of a list from a database. So I recieve the Data from my Ajax call, but they are a little bit to "late" so the rest of the actions start before the neccessary data is fully loaded (see screenshot). Is there a way to pause the script until the ajax data is fully loaded to use all of the information? Does this happen because of the "asynchronus = true" ?

Would be nice to get some answers, Thanks!

**Console shows this:**

[image]

I tried to re-order the script, but nothing really changed the problem.

```
var data_array = [];
var data = [];
var output = document.getElementById('entry-list');
/*Static Data Variables for Data Call*/
var name;
var priority;
var category;
var expiry;
/*Call AJAX*/
var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
var method = "GET";
var url = "getdata.php";
var asynchronous = true;
ajax.onreadystatechange = function()
{
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    /*getting return --> putting/convert json into array*/data.push(JSON.parse(this.responseText));
    console.log(data.length);

        for(var a = 0; a<data.length; a++){
             name = data[a].name;
             priority = data[a].priority;
             category = data[a].category;
             expiry = data[a].expiry;
             data_array.push("<li class='' id='list-item"+a+"' onclick='itemClick(this)'>"+name+" #"+a+", "+priority+"</li>");
            console.log("Array-entry added");
        }
    }
}
ajax.open(method, url, asynchronous);
//sending
ajax.send();
//recieving asnwer from getdata.php
console.log(data_array);
output.innerHTML = data_array;
```

Comment: Why is my Image not visible?

Comment: you should get familiar with the asynchronous behaviour of javascript. Some keywords here to google for are `asynchronous`, `promise`, `callback`, `generators`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to pause the script

You're thinking about this the wrong way.  Instead of trying to force operations to be blocking, instead re-structure your code to use the data in response to the asynchronous operation. Basically, the lines after //recieving asnwer from getdata.php should be in the callback function, not after it.

So instead of something like this:

```
ajax.onreadystatechange = function()
{
    // the rest of your code
}
ajax.open(method, url, asynchronous);
ajax.send();
console.log(data_array);
output.innerHTML = data_array;
```

You would do something like this:

```
ajax.onreadystatechange = function()
{
    // the rest of your code

    console.log(data_array);
    output.innerHTML = data_array;
}
ajax.open(method, url, asynchronous);
ajax.send();
```

Naturally, your code could get larger and more complex than just those two lines.  How you structure the more complex operations is up to you.  But the point is that those operations should be invoked by the response handler for the AJAX function.

Comment: I think it solved the problem for now, but I'd like to know why the logs echo out before the ajax? is it simply because of "loading time" or whats causing it?

Comment: @roubs3019: The first “A” in AJAX stands for “asynchronous”.  The operation is invoked, and while the network does its thing the code continues to execute.  When the network response is received it invokes the callback function you supplied it.

Answer (score -1):

You can do it this way with jquery AJAX.

```
$.ajax({

            method:"POST",
            url:"URL",
            data: {name:value},
            success: function (responseText) {

              //CODE HERE RUN AFTER DATA FULLY LOADED

            }

        });
```